# Redis BLPOP timeout in python

Tags: python, redis

I have this test code:

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis()
response = r.blpop('testkey', timeout=1)
print response
```

Run multiple times, this always takes significantly longer than 1 second, usually nearly 2 seconds. My redis server is local, so latency should not come into it. Does Redis not accurately time the timeout, or is it something the python client is doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, with your program, on top of the blpop time out, you also have to account for the startup time of the Python engine, the import of the packages, the establishment of the connection to Redis.

Furthermore, setting a time out does not provide any guarantee about the maximum wait time. It guarantees a minimum wait time when there is nothing to pop, which is different.

Note that for blpop, the time out is managed on server-side, not client-side. The server does it using a lazy algorithm which checks numclients/(hz*10) clients every hz times per second. Hz is a Redis parameter you can tune.

Comment: from the official manual, it seems that the timeout is actually configured on client https://redis.io/commands/blpop